# Questions filter "not" keyword

Tags: support, tags, search

This is [my filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%20or%20c%2B%2B%20or%20css%20or%20html%20or%20javascript%20or%20rust%20or%20python%20-angular%20-laravel%20-ember.js%20-vue.js%20-ios%20-asp.net%20-qt%20-django?sort=Newest&edited=true):
[image]

Why do I still see these questions?
[image]
[image]

Maybe I don’t understand how to use it correctly, but I can’t find any information on this topic.

Comment: The first one, because it's [c] or [c++] or [css] or [html] or [javascript] or [rust] or ([python] not [angular] not [laravel] not...). I don't think the `not`s are `and`ed with all of the `or`s. If that makes any sense.

Comment: If a question has 1 tag you follow and 1 tag you ignore, are you expecting to see that question or not?

Comment: @takendarkk If question has a tag that I ignore then I don't want to see it anyway

Comment: Can you post the content of search criteria as a string? It'll be in text on the top search bar.

Comment: So.. a small change and you may filter out all the unwanted: `([c] or [c++] or [css] or [html] or [javascript] or [rust] or [python]) -[angular] -[laravel] -[ember.js] -[vue.js] -[ios] -[asp.net] -[qt] -[django]`. Just use it directly in the top search bar. The Filter doesn't let one use parenthesis. The thing I noticed is that the results with [tag:python] seems to not have any of the "not" tags. So I expect it's a case of precedence.

Comment: @Scratte yes, thanks, this is what I need!

Comment: @Scratte write your answer, I will mark it as correct

Comment: I'm not a very prolific meta poster (I have reasons). You're welcome to self-answer using my comment, if you'd like. I can delete my comment too :) It was just an observation and not really enough for a full Answer for me. I'd have to research more and explain exactly what's going on.. with links to documentation and whatnot..

Comment: It's pity. Ok, I'll answer by myself. And there is no reason for you to delete your useful comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I understood, now this cannot be done using a filter. But you can realize it with a search bar expression like this:

```
([c] or [c++] or [css] or [html] or [javascript] or [rust] or [python]) -[angular] -[laravel] -[ember.js] -[vue.js] -[ios] -[asp.net] -[qt] -[django]
```

There you should combine the tags that you want to see into one group using rounded brackets.

Thanks, [Scratte](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12695027/scratte) for the [solution](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408530/questions-filter-not-keyword#comment850099_408530).